# local notification style coming up as banner, instead of alert

Tags: ios

so i'm working on my first app.  i'm trying to make an alarm that does OTHER STUFF.  from what i've found, I want UIlocalnotification.  So I've followed a few tutorials on the subject, and I have the notification fire.  However, it shows as a banner which quickly disappears.  I want it to look like the alarm clock alert... or any customer alert with OK, CANCEL.

Upon further reading in this forum, someone else asked the question, and if I'm reading it correctly only the USER can specify how the alert style looks.

Is this right?  Can I not FORCE an alert box to popup at a specified time?
And what about UIAlertView... that looks like what I'm looking for also... can that be used to go off like an alarm clock and x time in the future?

appreciate the input, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. The user is the one who decides what kind of notification he/she gets.

Comment: so what about UIAlertView... does that rely on what the user has setup also?

Comment: No, but that's within your app. A notification has the user interact outside of it.

Comment: ok thanks... Do you know how to setup the simulator to view notification as alert instead of banner?